# calculating the number of edges in a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am interested in knowing if there is any method to calculate no of pairs of non incident edges in a complete graph. Please let me know if somebody knows anything about it. Thank you

Comment: Hint: Pick an edge. How many other edges in the graph make a non-incident pair with that edge?

Comment: Also: welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: If the graph is embedded in a suitable way inside $\Bbb{R}^3$, then you can consider all edges non-intersecting. How is your graph represented? The answer depends on that.

Comment: @Joffan-  The process you told ,I have already tried and it gets really tedious as the graph gets larger and larger. Is there any set theory approach for finding it? I mean filtering out the 2 element subset which contains exactly only those pairs who form the non incident edges.

Comment: @crostul- Sorry, could you please elaborate how embedding a graph in 3d would work?

Answer (score 1):

Two methods:

---

Any pair of non-incident edges involves four vertices. So we can solve for $K_4$ and then apply that to every choice of $4$ vertices in $K_n$ for $n>4$.

Each vertex in $K_4$ has $3$ edges; each of those forms exactly one corresponding non-incident edge pair with edge between the other two vertices not incident to that first edge. So the solution of $K=4$ is $3$, and for $n\ge 4$, there are $3{n \choose 4}$ non-incident edge pairs in $K_n$.

---

Pick any edge in $K_n$. Then there are ${n-2 \choose 2}$ edges that are non-incident to that edge. $K_n$ has $n(n-1)/2$ edges, and repeating this process for each of these edges will select every non-incident edge pair twice, so the total number of non-incident edge pairs is $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}{n-2 \choose 2}$

---

These two solutions are, of course, the same number: $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}{n-2 \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{4}\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-4)!2!} = \frac{n!}{(n-4)!2!4} = 3\frac{n!}{(n-4)!4!} = 3{n \choose 4}$

Comment: @ Joffan- Thank you for your concerned reply. I shall work out and verify it and get back to you.

Comment: @vinod Let me know if there is anything you don't understand here.